# Rails 5 Api model not saving fields

Tags: strong-parameters, rails-api

I have a rails 5.2 API that currently creates and authenticates users (tested in Postman). However, I have added another model called Stories and when I attempt to create a new Story, a story is created but only the `id` attribute is saved.

Here is my StoriesController:

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_story, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /stories
  def index
    @stories = Story.all
    render json: @stories
  end

  # POST /stories
  def create
    @story = Story.new(story_params)
    if @story.save
      render json: @story, status: :created
    else
      render json: { errors: @story.errors.full_messages },
             status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # GET /stories/:id
  def show
    render json: @story
  end

  # PUT /stories/:id
  def update
    @story.update(story_params)
    head :no_content
  end

  # DELETE /stories/:id
  def destroy
    @story.destroy
    head :no_content
  end

  private

  def story_params
    # whitelist params
    params.permit(:title, :category, :summary)
  end

  def set_story
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Here is the request in Postman:
[image]

Here is the output in Postman:
[image]

I thought this was a params issue, but that does not seem to be it.

Answer (score 0):

man there is an extra opening bracket on your post payload on line 3.
The right json payload is.:

```
{
  "story": {
    "title": "Spiderman"
    "category": "Superhero"
    "summary": "new spiderguy ftw"
  }
}
```

I think there is a issue with your story_params method. The Story attributes "tittle", "category" and "summary" are nested in "story".

You can try this:

```
params.require(:story).permit(:title, :category, :summary)
```

Comment: That returns error missing parameters: "#<ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: story>"

Comment: Did you make the POST exactly like your Postman's screenshot?


{
 "story": {
 "tittle": "Spiderman ",
 "summary": "SuperHero",
 "category": "new spiderguy ftw"
 }
}

Comment: Yes. The screenshot is accurate. I also tried without nesting under story: but got the same result as if null params were passed.